# Google login after successfully auth not redirect to native build of PWA

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, progressive-web-apps

I have created a WebApp, In this app for authorization using google oauth2. It works fine in windows, ubuntu, android, and ios all browsers, and even though install as PWA and it works.

Using PWA builder, I'm trying to build the native ios application from the same PWA. The build is generated and launched successfully.

When clicking on google login. It redirects to accounts.google.com and creates a successful authorization process. and it holds with a spinner on accounts.google.com. and does not redirect to my application.

I did the same try with firebase, creating a firebase app and google sign-in method in authorization ( SignInWithPopup and SignInWithRedirect ) but the same behavior as oauth2 as above mentioned.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use `redirect` mode for Google auth.
Then add `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` in Podfile and run `pod install` in root folder.
Open .xcworkspace file and change Info.plist. Go to `Client ID for iOS` and add `iOS URL scheme` inside `CFBundleURLSchemes`

```
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>YOUR_DOT_REVERSED_IOS_CLIENT_ID</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

then add `Client ID` from `Client ID for iOS`

```
<key>GIDClientID</key>
<string>YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID</string>
```

then update your `WKAppBoundDomains`

```
<key>WKAppBoundDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>{your root url}</string>
        <string>accounts.google.com</string>
        <string>www.google.com</string>
        <string>accounts.youtube.com</string>
        {here add all 'Authorized redirect URIs' from 'Client ID for Web application'}
    </array>
```

and Build Product

also please this [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)